# Opening and Creating files in C Issue?

Tags: c, xcode, file, io, codeblocks

So, I have written a simple program in `C` which opens a file called `prog6_input.txt` and generates another file called `prog_output.txt`. However, the code below works perfectly for Windows but fails whenever I compile on a Mac. (I also assume this is having the same issue with create the file as well)

```
FILE *ptr_file = fopen("prog6_input.txt", "r");

// We Don't have a input file
if(!ptr_file) {
    perror("Error Reading Input file.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

For perror:`No Such file or directory`

The file, as seen in the screenshot below, is in the same directory. This works in windows, but does not in Mac OSX? Why is this and how would i fix it?

UPDATE: In order to vompile i used `make main` in the directory using terminal.

[image]

Comment: how do you run your program?

Comment: What does `errno` get set to after you try to open the file? Furthermore, what do you mean by "For perror:No Such file or directory"? Additionally, are you running the `main` program from your **Prog6** directory?

Comment: To run my Program, I double click the main (ecex) file. To clarify, that is what perror prints out. No file or directory. @hexturtle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should open up a terminal, `cd` to your **Prog6** directory, and run your executable with `./main`.

Comment: Wow, why does double clicking it create or expect the file to be in my Home directory and not the current directory of the executed code?

Comment: When you run the program by double clicking on it, there is no guarantee that the current working directory will be set to the directory in which the executable is located. As you observed, it might be set to your home directory or possibly some other directory. That said, the machine is not assuming anything about the location of files you will be using for I/O such as your prog6_input.txt. Rather, you're the one assuming that your files (e.g. prog6_input.txt) are located in the directory from which the program is being run. This is why it wasn't finding the file.

Comment: Thank you very much does. Thank you!